# Generate random string every 24 hours then refresh JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

What I have been trying to make may be a bit more complicated than I thought.
So what I am trying to accomplish is... **generating a random string of characters** through javascript (which I have the code for) but **only generating a new one at 12am or every 24hrs**.

The code I have should work (doesn't) and that's what I need help with.

```html
<div id="password1">
</div>
<script>
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getDay();
  var passwords = [makeid(10)[n]]; //want it to be 10... stay the same characters for 24hrs then change

  document.getElementById("password1").innerHTML = passwords[n];

  function makeid(length) {
    var result = [];
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result.push(characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
        charactersLength)));
    }
    return result.join('');
  }

</script>
```

Is it possible with javascript or not, is it a simple solution or syntax error? I have no idea...

*I looked in to this and couldn't find any similar posts...*

Comment: Please send help!!

Comment: Generating a new code every N hours should be easy enough but that would mean a browser running 24-7-365. You might find a server-side solution easier to implement

Comment: *not a new code, just a new string...

Comment: in this case interpret `code` and `string` as one and the same. A random string if you prefer. If you have a db at the backend it is easy enough to schedule it to generate a new code/string every N hours which can be queried from the client-side with Ajax/Server Sent Events or other...

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I am VERY new to javascript so I have NO idea what all that stuff means... I just want to use this string of randomly generated numbers and letters as a password, so that my password can change every day without me having to change it directly!

Comment: Is the password only for you? How is this code to be run - is it supposed to run automatically at a particular time? Will the password be stored anywhere? If it is a password - how will the authenticating party know the password?

Comment: The password is not only for me, it is for my small website - https://32iueuhfi423n89un32jnjdfh-password-fi2899f2iuneiofj345t3rg.nilentity.repl.co/YIXhdiofbioDHoiOJDFibidh8oIHFh9w992u4hfdsfjinBei.html

Comment: so - what lies behind the scenes to authenticate users? PHP & mySQL? ASP? Node.js?

Comment: HTML is the only code I used for that password website, if thats what you mean... I can add more languages if needed!

Comment: having username & passwords hardcoded in your javascript does not make for great security.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231038/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-html-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have coded your own password generator, I used your code to make a new password string lasting for 24 hours unless the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) gets cleard.

[Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) can be used too but localStorage and Cookie both are not properly runnable through sandbox environments, so try this on your own development environment. Please note that storing private values like passwords is not good for the security.

```
<div id="password1">
</div>
<script>
  function makeid(length) {
    var result = [];
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result.push(characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
        charactersLength)));
    }
    return result.join('');
  }
  const key = "keyForTheVulnurablePassword";
  if(localStorage.getItem(key) == null) {
    let expireDate = new Date();
    expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({pw:makeid(10), expire:expireDate}));
  }
  else {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    let storedExpireDate = new Date(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).expire);
    if(storedExpireDate <= currentDate) {
      while(storedExpireDate <= currentDate) {
        storedExpireDate.setDate(storedExpireDate.getDate() + 1);
      }
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({pw:makeid(10), expire:storedExpireDate}));
    }
  }
document.getElementById("password1").innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).pw;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="password1">
</div>
<script>
   function execute(){
         var d = new Date();
         var n = d.getDay();
         var passwords = [makeid(10)[n]]; //want it to be 10... stay the same characters for 24hrs then change
       
         document.getElementById("password1").innerHTML = passwords[n];
   }
  function makeid(length) {
    var result = [];
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result.push(characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
        charactersLength)));
    }
    return result.join('');
  }

const milisecondsUntil12Pm = 1000 // Write here the number of Miliseconds until 12 pm at the timeof run this script
setTimeout(()=> {
    execute()
 setInterval(()=> {
        execute()
    }, 86400000) // 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 miliseconds = 86400000 Miliseconds
}, milisecondsUntil12Pm) 


</script>
```

Comment: Remember to change the value for milisecondsUntil12Pm to the real time

Comment: @ManeulMB, When I refresh the page, the string should not change until after midnight!

Comment: So you need to calculate the number of miliseconds fron that moment until 12 pm and keep its value in the const milisecondsUntil12Pm

Comment: That still doesnt work... I want to use this string as a password for the day, so it CANT change!